# valueforkey when object property is readonly and Calculated(derived)

Tags: iphone, ios, key-value-coding

I am having trouble calling valueforkey method on a property that is calculated. For example:

```
@interface Value : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,getter = toString,readonly)NSString *stringVal;

-(NSString*) toString;
@end
```

When I call [instanceOfValueClass valueForKey:@"stringVal"] , It says it is not key-value compliant. Exact Message is :

[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key stringVal.

Does key value coding works on derived properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the getter method to `toString`, so

```
 [instanceOfValueClass valueForKey:@"toString"]
```

should work. Note that you don't have to "rename" the getter method, you could just
override the default getter:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSString *stringVal;

- (NSString *)stringVal
{
    NSString *s = ...; // compute property value
    return s;
}
```

Then both `instance.stringVal` and `[instance valueForKey:@"stringVal"]`
would work, with the "same key".

Comment: @Jignesh: What I think is that KVC looks for the getter method, not the property name.